# Hive ParseException - cannot recognize input in Select Clause

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

Am trying to write a Union All query in hive. Below is my query

```
Create table test.Final_Union_Table as
    Select xyz.column_1,xyz.column_2,xyz.column_3
        From (
        Select a.column_1, a.column_2, a.column_3
                From test.Union_table1 a
                Union All
                Select b.column_1, b.column_2, b.column_3
                From test.Final_Table b)xyz;
```

Am getting the error below

```
ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'z' '.' 'Column_1' in select clause
```

Would appreciate some help and guidance here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is right,try this

```
Create table test.Final_Union_Table as
    Select column1,column2,column3
        From (
        Select a.column_1 as column1, a.column_2 as column2, a.column_3 as column3
                From test.Union_table1 a
                Union All
                Select b.column_1 as column1, b.column_2 as column2, b.column_3 as column3
                From test.Final_Table b)xyz;
```

Note- Data type should be same for particular column in both tables example a.column_1 and b.column_1 should have same data type;